# Capture text input in Google Web Designer expandable banner

Tags: javascript, html, google-web-designer

I'm creating an expandable banner with Google Web Designer and I want to allow the user to type their name/email in to a textbox and to capture the value to report in the campaign.

Going to the Tag tool I created an input field and dragged it to the page. When I preview I can type text in there, but I can't raise any events and it doesn't log anything to the console.

How can I capture the users input? I thought it would be easy as it supports HTML5, but I can't see how to wire up my input field

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality for accomplishing anything with form inputs since GWD is intended to be used to create ads for Google's Ad Network which does not support any interaction other than clicks. However, you can use Javascript just like you would if you weren't using Google Web Designer.

You would just give the input an ID and create a button to grab the value of the input and then you could do whatever you want with it.

For example, if you added an input with the ID of `name` and a button with the ID of `button` you would add this in your `Code view` within the `gwd-init-code` script tags:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("name").value;
    alert(inputVal);
};
```

Comment: I can see how that gets me the value entered in the input box. How do I report that value in the events in the campaign / Studio?

Comment: What about using something like the `exitQueryString` method found on the `Enabler` class? google docs for richmedia: https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/176242?hl=en